# Error: "No canisters in the configuration file." Dfinity Motoko dfx

Tags: ipc, dfinity

[image]

I don't understand whats going wrong here, I'm fed up with Dfinity and today I realise the problem of Un-Maintained piece of technology and so much of uncertainities in Web 3 now. I wasn't able to find anything related.

Comment: May you share us your `dfx.json` and is your project open-source ? Likewise it will be easier to have a look at why it doesn't work. Note: IMO your question isn't related to *Inter-process Communication* while you use the `ipc` tag. I guess you meant `icp`.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I finally fixed the issue

Try updating your dfx.json with the adequate configuration, and also delete .dist file if you have it before your deployment.

dfx.json

`

{

"canisters":

{

```
  "[your canister name]":
      {
    "main": "src/[your canister name]/main.mo",

    "type": "motoko"
  },

  "[your canister name]_assets": {
    "dependencies": [
      "[your canister name]"
    ],

    "frontend": {
      "entrypoint": "src/[Your canister name]_assets/src/index.html"
    },

    "source": [
      "src/[Your canister name]_assets/assets",
      "dist/[your cannister name]_assets/"
    ],

    "type": "assets"
  }
},

"defaults": {
  "build": {
    "args": "",
    "packtool": ""
  }
},

"dfx": "[Ensure you put your Dfx version]",
"networks": {
  "local": {
    "bind": "127.0.0.1:8000",
    "type": "ephemeral"
  }

},

"version": 1
```

}

Comment: FYI, the frontend canister does not have to have the "assets" suffix. That was the earlier default schema naming convention, as an "asset canister" is the kind of icp smart contract (or "canister") that can host and serve the frontend. Only place it's needed is in the source entry, "src/[frontend name]/assets", and even then maybe configurable and just acting as raw assets directory of the frontend.